# Can't look up object property with a variable for some reason

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know how this SHOULD work. if I've got a variable x="property" and an object that looks like y={property: "value"}, then y[x] should return "value". This worked for me until now but some sort of weird bug happens in my code. Here's the function I'm having issues with:

```js
const { textToSpeech } = require("../text-to-speech/tts");
const data = require("../Data/Data").data;

const genericSendMessage = async (userMessage, assistant) => {
  try{
    let res = await assistant.message({
      workspace_id: process.env.TTS_WORKSPACE,
      input: {"text": userMessage}
    })
    res = await JSON.stringify(res["output"]["text"][0], null, 2)
    res = generateResponse(res);
    await textToSpeech(res);
    return res;
  }catch(err){
    console.log("error in genericSendMessage:\n",err)
  }
}

const generateResponse = (watsonCode) => {
  console.log("========================\nwatsonCode: ",watsonCode,"\ndata: ",data,"\ndata[watsonCode]: ",data[watsonCode])
  console.log(Object.values(data))
    return data[watsonCode][Math.floor(Math.random()*data[watsonCode].length())]
}

module.exports = genericSendMessage;
```

If you look at this console.log:

```
console.log("========================\nwatsonCode: ",watsonCode,"\ndata: ",data,"\ndata[watsonCode]: ",data[watsonCode])
```

both data and watsonCode are consoled fine and are what they should be. data is an object and watsonCode is a string that corresponds to a property of that object, but data[watsonCode] is undefined... every time. The same thing happens if i make data an array and watsonCode a number (index). I have no clue how this is possible. The same thing worked before and if I hardcode watsonCode to be Number("1") right above the console.log, it works fine, but if fetch watsonCode and get "1" then do data[Number(watsonCode)] it's undefined. I tried doing typeof(watsonCode) in the generateResponse function to see if it's somehow still a promise but no, it's a string.

Here's what the console.log looks like for the array version(shortened):

```
========================
watsonCode:  "1" 
data:  [[...],[...],[...],...] //I removed the data here as it is somewhat sensitive but it's just a 2D array of strings
data[Number(watsonCode)]:  undefined
error in genericSendMessage:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

My question is how this is possible, what's happening and how do I fix it so i can reference the objects properties normally?

Comment: the variables may be ok, but the calculation Math.random()*data[watsonCode] might be returning an undefined?

Comment: Looks like `data` is an array, not an object. You're right `data[Number(watsonCode)]` should exist (as long as data as at least 2 elements, for `watsonCode = "1"`) and it should work as it would if it were an object... but still, this is a really cumbersome way to access array data. I mean, if you want it to be an array, why don't you use normal indexes, instead of casting strings to numbers?

Comment: I don't want it to be an array. I just converted it to one to see if I could get around the problem that way, the initial data was an object and I still want it to be and object with named keys. The array thing is just me testing to see if that would work. It didn't. So, to recap, I can't access object properties OR array indexes using watsonCode as it is here and I have no clue why.

Comment: Is the `watsonCode` in the correct character encoding you expect for `Number(watsonCode)`?  You say it is a string, and it works when you hardcode a `"1"`, but what is the value of returning the converted number?

Comment: now that I've consoled Number(watsonCode) I guess it really must be encoding. The result is NaN. How do I change the encoding? A cursory google search ended up with several posts none of which seem to be what I want.